# Steam Authentication W/ React & Nodejs API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, openid, steam

I am trying to allow users to sign up for my site with steam. Setting it up for google was a breeze but this openId business is much less intuitive. My react app is at localhost:3000 while my node api is running on localhost:3010. When I press my login button on my UI, it redirects me to steam, I press sign in there, and then I get the "InternalOpenIDError: Failed to verify assertion" error. I have tried many configurations, always getting this result. My API code is below

```
equire("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3010;
const router = require("./routes/router");
const db = require("./models/index");
const http = require("http").createServer(app);
router.use(express.json());
const corsOptions = {
  origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "https://gangs.gg"], // http://localhost:3000 for electron, otherwise deployed ui
  methods: "GET,POST",
  allowedHeaders: "Content-Type,Authorization",
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions), router);
app.use(require("prerender-node").set("prerenderToken", "pmAz691dTZfZ6GTrUiZZ"));
const path = require("path");
const { main } = require("./startup/startup");
const messageController = require("./controllers/message-controller");
//Steam
const passport = require("passport");
const SteamStrategy = require("passport-steam").Strategy;
const session = require("express-session");

//START STEAM
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    name: process.env.SESSION_NAME,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {
  done(null, obj);
});
passport.use(
  new SteamStrategy(
    {
      returnURL:
        process.env.IS_PROD === "1" ? "https://www.gangs.gg/steam/return" : "http://localhost:3010/steam/return",
      realm: process.env.IS_PROD === "1" ? "https://www.gangs.gg" : "http://localhost:3000",
      apiKey: process.env.STEAM_API_KEY,
    },
    (identifier, profile, done) => {
      profile.identifier = identifier;
      done(null, profile);
    }
  )
);
//STEAM ROUTES
const redirectUrl = process.env.IS_PROD === "1" ? "https://www.gangs.gg/login" : "http://localhost:3000/login";

app.get("/steam", passport.authenticate("steam", { successRedirect: "/", failureRedirect: "/" }), function (req, res) {
  console.log("authenticating!! ", res);
  res.redirect("/");
});

// GET /auth/steam/return
//   Use passport.authenticate() as route middleware to authenticate the
//   request.  If authentication fails, the user will be redirected back to the
//   login page.  Otherwise, the primary route function function will be called,
//   which, in this example, will redirect the user to the home page.
app.get(
  "/steam/return",
  passport.authenticate("steam", { failureRedirect: redirectUrl }),
  // function (req, res, next) {
  //   req.url = req.originalUrl;
  //   next();
  // },
  function (req, res) {
    console.log("authenticatedddd!! ", res);
    res.redirect("/");
  }
);
```

Comment: Bumping this to hopefully get someone's attention who has experience, there isn't much documented online about a full stack steam auth setup using react.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the code locally and the only thing that is incorrect is the returnURL from the SteamStrategy object, the return url must be an endpoint at your api. Steam will complain if the realm and the return addresses are different, here is the working code that i've tested (only the important parts):

```js
passport.use(
    new SteamStrategy(
        {
            returnURL:
                process.env.IS_PROD === "1" ? "https://www.gangs.gg/steam/return" : "http://localhost:3002/steam/return",
            realm: process.env.IS_PROD === "1" ? "https://www.gangs.gg" : "http://localhost:3002",
            apiKey: process.env.STEAM_API_KEY,
        },
        (identifier, profile, done) => {
            profile.identifier = identifier;
            done(null, profile);
        }
    )
);

const redirectUrl = process.env.IS_PROD === "1" ? "https://www.gangs.gg/login" : "http://localhost:3002/login";

app.get("/steam", passport.authenticate("steam", { successRedirect: "/", failureRedirect: "/" }), function (req, res) {
    console.log("authenticating!! ", res);
    res.redirect("/");
});


app.get(
    "/steam/return",
    passport.authenticate("steam", { failureRedirect: redirectUrl }),
    function (req, res) {
        console.log("authenticatedddd!! ", req.user);
        res.redirect("/");
    }
);

const http = require("http").createServer(app);

http.listen("3002", () => {
    console.log("listening")
})
```